# How do I change the poisson equation to solve for an alternative answer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pde

I'm trying to redo the Poisson equation so that ∂²Φ /∂x² = 2x² - 0.5x + exp(x). Every time I try and input the right-hand side of the equation it comes up with a syntax error, any help would very much be appreciated.

```
% Solving of 1D Poisson equation
% using finite differences

% Clearing memory and figures
clear all
clf

% Define 1D numerical model
xsize=100; % Model size in horizontal direction, m
Nx=101; % Number of grid points
dx=xsize/(Nx-1); % Gridstep, m
x=0:dx:xsize; % Coordinates of grid points, m

% Defining global matrixes
L=zeros(Nx,Nx); % Koefficients in the left part
R=zeros(Nx,1); % Right parts of equations


% Composing global matrixes
% by going through all grid points
for j=1:1:Nx
    % Discriminating between BC-points and internal points
    if(j==1 || j==Nx)
        % BC-points
        L(j,j)=1; % Left part
        R(j)=0; % Right part
    else
        % Composing Poisson eq. d2T/dx2=1
        %
        % ---T(j-1)------T(j)------T(j+1)---- STENCIL
        %
        % 1/dx2*T(j-1)+(-2/dx2)*T(j)+1/dx2*T(j+1)=1
        %
        % Left part of j-equation
        L(j,j-1)=1/dx^2; % T(j-1)
        L(j,j)=-2/dx^2; % T(j)
        L(j,j+1)=1/dx^2; % T(j+1)
        % Right part
        R(j)=2x;
    end
end

% Solve the matrix
S=L\R;

% Reload solutions
T=zeros(1,Nx); % Create array for temperature, K
for j=1:1:Nx
    T(j)=S(j);
end

% Visualize results
figure(1); clf
plot(x,T,'o r') % Plotting results
```

Again, I appreciate any help in this matter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is clear: "input the right-hand side of the equation it comes up with a syntax error", to correct the error you should properly define the right-hand side of the equation:

```
R(j)=2*x(j)^2-0.5*x(j) + exp(x(j));
```

Since it depends on `x`, you should point to each element `j` when calculating the coefficients in the for loop on the left and right hand sides of the equation.

Analytical solution of the PDE is:
[image]

Changing this line of code and plotting the discretized and analytical solutions produces

```
% Visualize results
figure(1); clf
plot(x,T,'o r');
hold on
plot(x , 0.166667*x.^4-0.0833333*x.^3-268811714181613573321934397213431784538112*x+exp(x)-1)
```

[image]

which seems correct. Differences are due to discretization itself.

Comment: Hi thank you very much, could you by any chance direct me to what you used for the analytical solution. I'm new to this area and trying to get my baring as to what to use

Comment: check the https://www.wolframalpha.com/ website